# Using C# 4.0 and dynamic objects, how to create a dynamic proxy to a web service?

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, dynamic, soap, wsdl

I am trying to determine if it would be possible to create a dynamic (as in using the dynamic object feature of C# 4.0) proxy to a web service (SOAP).

Basically, I would want to give the dynamic object the URL of a WSDL then it would construct the proxy using it. It would then be possible to call any web method with any parameter.

I specifically don't want to use the proxy generation from Visual Studio as this is static.

I googled the web but the only thing I could find is an old library for C# 2.0 to create a dynamic proxy by creating an assembly on the fly: http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/dynwslib

There's even more at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/04/27/dynamically-invoking-a-web-service.aspx

Comment: http://codemine.net/post/Code-for-Dynamically-generating-webproxy-%28CNet%29.aspx

Comment: @AlexanderS. Well, it still generate an assembly and does not use DYNAMIC from C# 4...

Comment: Basically, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exists.